# Variation of the (Chern) curvature with respect to the metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E\rightarrow X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle, for any Hermitian metric $h$ on $E$ we denote by $F_h$ the curvature of the Chern connection associated to $h$. Fix a metric $h_0$ and consider a one-parameter family of metrics $h_t=h_0(g_t\cdot ,g_t\cdot)$ with $g_t\in \Gamma(End(E))$.

I am interested in finding a formula for 
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}F_{h_t}$$

If someone has a reference ill be grateful

Comment: You can put the formula for $h_t$ into the formula for the curvature of a metric, differentiate, and set $t=0$. Look at papers on curvature flows for guidance on how this goes, if not the exact formula itself.